# How can I check if I have written a number or a letter in c++?

Tags: c++

This is my first time on stackoverflow. I can not figure out how I can check if I have written a number or a letter. If i have written a letter I want the program to say that I neat to write a correct number.
Everything is working except the part where the program asks me to enter the correct number, then it goes in infinete loop. I added my code for better understanding.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{       
    char atbilde;
    int t=1;
    
    while(t>0){
    
        float x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3;
        cout<<"Write triangle coordinates!" <<endl;
        cin>>x1 >>y1 >>x2 >>y2 >>x3 >>y3;
        float a, b, c, a1, b1, c1, p1, s1, ah1, bh1, ch1;

        float ah, bh, ch;

        int aw=2, bw=2, cw=2, ahw=2, bhw=2, chw=2;

        float s, p;
        a=sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2)+(y1-y2)*(y1-y2));
        b=sqrt((x2-x3)*(x2-x3)+(y2-y3)*(y2-y3));
        c=sqrt((x3-x1)*(x3-x1)+(y3-y1)*(y3-y1));


        while(a1>10){
            a1=a1/10;
            aw++;
        }
        b1=b;
        while(b1>10){
            b1=b1/10;
            bw++;
        }
        c1=c;
        while(c1>10){
            c1=c1/10;
            cw++;
        }
        p=(a+b+c)/2;
        s=sqrt(p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c));

        ah=(2*s)/a;
        bh=(2*s)/b;
        ch=(2*s)/c;

        ah1=ah;
        while(ah1>10){
            ah1=ah1/10;
            ahw++;
        }
        bh1=bh;
        while(bh1>10){
            bh1=bh1/10;
            bhw++;
        }
        ch1=ch;
        while(ch1>10){
            ch1=ch1/10;
            chw++;
        }
        if(ah > 0 && bh > 0 && ch > 0){
            cout<<"Height of side A is " <<setprecision(ahw) <<ah <<endl <<"Height of side B is "             <<setprecision(bhw) <<bh <<endl <<"Height of side C is " <<setprecision(chw) <<ch <<endl;
            cout<<"Do you want to repeat? j-Yes! n-No!" <<endl;
            cin>>atbilde;
            
            while(atbilde!='j'&& atbilde!='n'){
                cout<<"Write a correct letter!" <<endl;
                cin>>atbilde;
            }
            if(atbilde=='n'){
                break;
            }
        }
        else{
            cout<<"Height can not be calculates!"<<endl;
            cout<<"Want to repeat? j-Yes! n-No!" <<endl;
            cin>>atbilde;
            while(atbilde!='j'&& atbilde!='n'){
                cout<<"Write a correct leter!" <<endl;
                cin>>atbilde;
            }
            if(atbilde=='n'){
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to read the input into a string and then you can parse the string and do whatever you want.

Comment: Welcome, please provide [mcve] with the excepted and actual behaviour. The code posted is unnecessarily complicated and not commented at all.

Comment: Well, you need to set `t` and you need to set `a1`.  `t` is always 1

Comment: A google search for "validate numeric input c++ site:stackoverflow.com" brings up hundreds of questions and answers that were posted here, over the years, on this very same topic. You didn't find any one of them to be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

To check if an input is a float, a simple way I can think of right now is inputting it into a string, then trying to convert it to a float, then catching the exception.

```
string s;
float f;
cin >> s;
try{
    f = stof(s);
    // The input is a float (if this is in a while loop, you may want to break here)
    cout << "The input is a float";
}catch(invalid_argument ia){
    // The input is not a float
    cout << "The input is not a float";
}
```

Here is an example of checking if the input is a float. You can put it in places such as a while loop, and replace the things under the comments with things such as outputting what you want or breaking the loop.

As for your other problems, I don't completely understand what you are trying to do, and your code is a little messy, mind clarifying a little? Thank you.

**Edit:**
What stof does is that it changes a string to a float, if the string is not a float, it will throw an invalid argument exception. [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/) is some information about exceptions in C++.

Here is an example of an implementation of something that asks you for a float input until your input is a float.

```
string s;
float x;
while(1){
    try{
        cout << "Input x\n";
        cin >> s;
        x = stof(s);
        break;
    }catch(invalid_argument e){
        cout << s << " is not a float, please input x again\n";
    }
}
cout << "Thank you. Your float is " << x << '\n';
```

Comment: The task I must do is - I must write coordinates of a triangle and find out the height of its sides. If I write everything correctly it will work, but if instead of coordinates I will write a letter, for example "a", it will go in the loop couting                  cout<<"Height of side A is " <<setprecision(ahw) <<ah <<endl <<"Height of side B is "             <<setprecision(bhw) <<bh <<endl <<"Height of side C is " <<setprecision(chw) <<ch <<endl;
            cout<<"Do you want to repeat? j-Yes! n-No!" <<endl;

 cout<<"Write a correct letter!" <<endl;

Comment: Thank you for your help, but unfortunately I do not understand what you wrote there :(. I'm studiying programming for the first year.